# Symfony app/cache (with 777 permissions) folder not writable error

Tags: php, symfony, caching, permissions, centos

The specific error is:

> Cache directory "/var/www/html/website/app/cache/dev" is not writable.

The mentioned folder has 777 permissions tough. Unhappy and frustrated I applied those permissions to the entire website folder

> chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/website/

But still, I had no luck. I tried to delete the folder:

> rm -rf app/dev

It recreates correctly the folder when I try to access the website but still, that error persists.

This website it's been migrated from another VPS so I even tried to

> chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/website/

reset the ownership but it was unsuccesful.

In the same VPS there are several virtual hosts running with zero problems. It's a CentOS 7. What am I missing?

Comment: Your chown command is missing a slash before the ``var``.

Comment: Yeah sorry, i misstyped here. Edited, thank you.

Comment: You should never chmod 777 all of your web files. What version of Symfony is this? the remove command of you dev folder won't work because dev is not located in app, but in app/cache. so execute the following: `rm -rf app/cache/dev` and `chmod -R 777 app/cache`.

Comment: @CirykPopeye thank you for your answer. I would **never** chmod 777 an entire website, this was made on a staging server by the way. The version is 2.8. I already tried to rm that specifc folder but I had no luck. Before asking here I tried a lot of stuff tbh. I guess the problem could be related to an alleged corruption of the Symfony base. I will try to reinstall it and I will let you know.

Comment: Where did you configure your cache to write in? Symfony can, but does nit have to user different folders for each environment. 
Locally that will be mostly dev and test, but on a server it can also be stage or prod. However you can configure symfony to write them all into one folder.

Comment: They were separated for environment at the moment of this request. I momentarily moved them into /dev/shm/ and it works perfectly. Still I want to understand what's the problem and **why** symfony can't write in website/app/cache/**